# I can't use method declared in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use [this project](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar) but I end up with a problem. 
The main goal is to set some gradient color to UiNavigationBar using StoryBoard.

1 -

```
#import "CRGradientNavigationBar.h"
```

2 -

[image] **BECOMES** [image]

3 -

```
    // array of colors
UIColor *firstColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:104.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *secondColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:90.0f/255.0f blue:58.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
NSArray *colorsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstColor, secondColor, nil];

    // setting the navigation bar color
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintGradientColors:colorsArray];

    // 
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.navigationBar);
```

***The error is***

```
No visible @interface for 'UINavigationBar' declares the selector 'setBarTintGradientColors:'
```

knowing that `setBarTintGradientColors` is declared in [CRGradientNavigationBar.h](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar/blob/master/CRGradientNavigationBar/CRGradientNavigationBar.h)

***And the NSLog output is***

```
2014-06-23 21:07:04.388 Project[1794:60b] <CRGradientNavigationBar: 0xa5324d0; baseClass = UINavigationBar; frame = (0 20; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa536060>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa5327e0>>
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.navigationController.navigationBar returns a UINavigationBar, not a CRGradientNavigationBar. You could cast it:

```
[(CRGradientNavigationBar *)(self.navigationController.navigationBar) setBarTintGradientColors:colorsArray];
```